# Bash while loop with two string conditions

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop

I have run into a bit of a problem with my bash script. My script among other things is starting a server that takes some time to get going. In order to combat the long startup, I have put in a while loop that queries the server to see if its running yet.

```
while [ $running -eq 0 ]; do
echo "===" $response "===";
if [ "$response" == "" ] || [ "$response" == *"404 Not Found"* ]; then
    sleep 1;
    response=$(curl $ip:4502/libs/granite/core/content/login.html);
else
   running=1;
fi
done
```

When exiting the loop $response equals the "404" string. If thats the case, the thing should still be in the loop, shouldn't it? Seems my loop is exiting prematurely.

Joe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[ .. ]` doesn't match by glob. Use `[[ .. ]]`:

```
if [ "$response" == "" ] || [[ "$response" == *"404 Not Found"* ]]; then
```

Comment: Note that `[[ ]]` is a bash extension, so make sure the script starts with `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`. There are ways to do an equivalent test in plain POSIX shell syntax, but they aren't nearly as clean.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but even with your changes, I am still seeing the loop exiting while response has the 404 string in it.

Comment: @JoeAndolina Just a thought - have you verified this with another site   that definitely gives a 404?

Comment: @Preet, My output in the loop is surrounded with **===** and my output after the loop is surrounded with **+++**,

`=== <html><head><title> 404 Not Found </title>... ===`,

- after - 

`+++ <html><head><title> 404 Not Found </title>... +++`,

Comment: @JoeAndolina Your echo statement destroyed whitespace, so if the text contained e.g.  two spaces or a no-break space, it would print the same but not match. `echo "$response" > file` with quotes would let you investigate.

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks again for your response. The server outputs several responses and after looking at the echo output, there were line breaks and things in the output I had not accounted for. Since there are 4 various outputs that I need to track the string length solution below is better for this case.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why my original script was failing. I assume it has to do with the fact that I was comparing against HTML. To get my script working I wound up using the string length instead of the content. The using the following comparator has everything working swimmingly.

```
if [ -z "$response" ] || [ ${#response} -lt 100 ]; then
```

Thanks for the help,
Joe